# Total sum of characters over partitions with distinct parts

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, enumerative-combinatorics

In [my earlier quest](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403957/total-sum-of-characters-of-the-symmetric-group-fraks-n), we looked at $\chi_{\mu}^{\lambda}=$value of an irreducible character of the symmetric group $\frak{S}_n$, where $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are (unrestricted) [partitions of $n$](https://oeis.org/A000041). Then, the question was about this total sum:
$$\frak{s}_n:=\sum_{\mu\vdash n}\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\chi_{\mu}^{\lambda}=?$$

This time around, I wish to ask:

> **QUESTION 1.** If $\mu$ and $\lambda$ run through [partitions of distinct parts of $n$](https://oeis.org/A000009), then what is the value of the sum
> $$\frak{t}_n:=\sum_{\mu\vdash n}\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\chi_{\mu}^{\lambda}=? \tag1$$

> **QUESTION 2.** What is a conceptual or representation-theoretic interpretation of (1)?

Comment: Not really an answer, but maybe a start: partitions with distinct parts (more often called "strict" partitions in this context) are related to the *projective* representation theory of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$ in much the same way that usual partitions are related to the ordinary representation theory.

Comment: See also spin characters as discussed in https://doi.org/10.5802/alco.92.